# what is new in iPhone 5 and ios6 for development?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When iPhone 4 was released , there was a special hardware for Location based services and APIs.But when i saw iphone 5 and ios6 , there was simple some built in applications and some hardware improvements.Is there any special in iOS6 and iphone 5 for development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can inform yourself about all new feature after login to the iOS Dev Center. There is an area called "what is new in iOS 6"

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html